# Why doesn't Lady use Soulcatcher's true name?

Tags: black-company

I'll try to write this with few spoilers.

Given that Lady knows the true names of each of her taken, why can't she name Soulcatcher when

> Soulcatcher becomes an enemy

later in the series?

I'm a quarter of the way through the last book so maybe I just need to wait and see if this ends up happening, but I would think if Lady was going to name Soulcatcher, she would have already.

Edit:
I've read more and found [Lady mentions Soulcatcher's name](https://books.google.com/books?id=H2ZQdlsrcRcC&pg=PA627&dq=Howler%27s%20got%20a%20carpet%20ready&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN7q6K397KAhXCbj4KHcb0AsUQ6AEILzAA#v=onepage&q=Sileth%27s&f=false). Why hasn't this been used to nullify Soulcatcher?

Comment: "Sylith" is a name that Dominator tries to use to strip Lady from her powers and then he knows Soulcatcher's name (because he made her "Taken"), hence he wouldn't try to use this name if he knew it already belongs to Lady's sister. See the [comments here](http://blackcompany.wikia.com/wiki/Soulcatcher)

Answer (score 1):

### We don't know that Lady knew Soulcatcher's name

Soulcatcher was one of the original Ten Who Were Taken and was created by Dominator, not by Lady, so its quite possible that she didn't know her name

> And thats even while they were sisters!!

Please note, that Lady went to long pains to protect her name, up to killing her twin sister, so its quite reasonable to assume that Soulcatcher done the same.

Also (here my memory might be bit vague, its been years), to use True Name to strips sorcerer's magic away, he or she needs to hear it (and directly addressed by it, so casually screaming someone's name wouldn't work), and Soulcatcher prefer's to use subterfuge and attack from distance and by proxies.

Comment: Soulcatcher is the Lady's sister.  Perhaps not the twin, but still you'd think she'd know it.  I suppose that by giving Soul's name, the Lady would be making discovering her own by process of elimination easier.

Comment: That makes sense as Soulcatcher never used Lady's name, but between the Dominator, Limper and finally Silent, the 4 names thought to be the 4 sisters were all spoken. You would think it's worth a shot to say those again around SC..